# Hovering List goes out of alignment

Tags: html, css

I created this Hovering list. It has two sub fields, employee visa and Family visa. When I move the mouse, the sub fields goes down too much. There any way to fix this without increase the Width of the whole side menu?

[image: 2 Sub lists go too much down upon mouse hovering]

HTML List

```
  <ul id="menu" >           
            <li><a href="#">&#10148; Visa</a>                
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                       <a href="LoadEmployeeVisa">Employee Visa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="#">Family Visa</a>
                    </li>                   
                </ul>
             </ul>
      </ul>
```

The CSS

```
<style>        
        /*Initialize*/
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: decimal;

}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;

}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;

}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "goes down too much. "

Comment: You have invalid HTML there – you can not have a `ul` as child of a `ul`, you need a `li` in between.

Comment: you can set top:20px instead of 30px

Comment: What I mean by "goes down too much" is, the words "Employee" and "Visa" should come into a one line, not two lines. as the image shows. Same goes to the "Family Visa too"

Comment: Well those word go into two lines, because there is not enough space for them to be next to each other on one line … so you need to either increase the width of the whole thing, or reduce the margin/padding on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the width to 200px. Hope it solves the problem.

```
#menu li ul.sub-menu {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```css
 /*Initialize*/
ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: decimal;

}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;

}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
    position: relative;

}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
    margin:-1px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu" >           
            <li><a href="#">&#10148; Visa</a>                
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                       <a href="LoadEmployeeVisa">Employee Visa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="#">Family Visa</a>
                    </li>                   
                </ul>
             </ul>
      </ul>
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/jp8hyLew/)

Note: Removed `width:100px` you can set it to `150 px or 200px` if needed.
Also changed `top:30px` to `top:20px`. 
However `top:xyz` is not needed though.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the text from going onto a second line:

```
.sub-menu li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will keep the text on a single line, but it will stick out the side of your menu. If this is not desirable, you can make it look nicer by adding this:

```
.sub-menu li {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
/*Initialize*/

ul#menu {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
ul#menu,
ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li,
ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
/*Link Appearance*/

ul#menu li a,
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/

ul#menu li {
  position: relative;
}
/*sub menu*/

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">&#10148; Visa</a> 
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="LoadEmployeeVisa">Employee Visa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Family Visa</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```